# jquery-ias - History extension button styling

Tags: infinite-scroll, jquery-ias

I'm using the Infinite Ajax scroll plugin (http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/), which is working really good for me, except one thing.

I'm using all four extension (Trigger, Spinner,Paging, History, in this order) by default, the plugin hide all pagination links (generated by the server) and display the load more items link on the top (by History plugin) and on the bottom (by Trigger plugin) of the container.

I can override the link (both text and class) on the Trigger extension, but the History extension use the same values so you will see the same button above and under the container.

I tried to add the same parameters to the History extension but it is not working:

```
        var ias = $.ias({
            container:  ".js-job-container",
            item:       ".item--job ",
            pagination: ".pagination",
            next:       ".pagination-direction-tab-next",
            delay:      0
        });


        ias.extension(new IASTriggerExtension({  text: "View more", html: '<a class="button button--view-more button--action">{text}</a>' }));
        ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension());           
        ias.extension(new IASPagingExtension());
        ias.extension(new IASHistoryExtension({ text:'Previous elements', html: '<a class="button button--view-more button--action">{text}</a>', prev: '.pagination-direction-tab-prev'}));
```

Is there any option which i missed to override the default text and class?

Cheers,
Geza

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is added in v2.1.2.

See [textPrev](http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/docs/extension-trigger.html#textprev) and [htmlPrev](http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/docs/extension-trigger.html#htmlprev) options.